# How to assign a variable that passed a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, function, loops, conditional-statements

I have an app that is essentially a random number gen and assigns it to some horse breeds. I need to have a condition that checks if ANY variable AND only 1 variable is equal to 1.

I want something like this that assigns the value that is passed to a variable and then checks it to a user-inputted variable

I tried to mockup something like this, but it seems to only pass boolean results

```
var balance = ''
var target = getText("horseIn")
var leverage = getNumber("levIn")
var horses = {
    Appaloosa: getNumber("h1pos"),
    frenchTrotter: getNumber("h2pos"),
    Fresian: getNumber("h3pos"),
    Hackney: getNumber("h4pos"),
    Faflinger: getNumber("h5pos"),
    pasoFino: getNumber("h6pos"),
}
var winner = null;
onEvent("startM", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("selectAmount");
});


onEvent("submitBet", "click", function( ) {
  if (getNumber("userAmount") >0){
    setScreen("horseScreen");
    updateScreen();
    console.log(horses)
    while (winner == null) {
      for (i in horses) {
        if (horses[i] == 1){
          winner = i;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    setText("userAmount","Please input an amount!");
  }
  console.log(winner)
});

function updateScreen(){
  setText("h1pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  setText("h2pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  setText("h3pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  setText("h4pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  setText("h5pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  setText("h6pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}

function pnl(){
  setScreen("endScreen");
  if (target == winner) {
    console.log("Winner");
}
}
```

I am setting the variables like this:

```
let Appaloosa = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
let frenchTrotter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
let Fresian = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
let Hackney = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
let Faflinger = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
let pasoFino = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

so I need to repeat the process if none of them work.

Comment: Do you want to get the variable name or the value of the variable?

Comment: Variable name, I also need to make sure it's only 1 value. I am trying to just do a for loop across a dict of vars now

Comment: It looks like your condition will be `true` for any and all values of any of the horses (assuming they were not assigned values of `nul`). Have you tested cases where none are set to 1? You probably need a more exhaustive and explicit comparison. One possibly would be to make all pair-wise `XOR` comparisons. Or (simpler) loop all horses adding any with value==1 to an array and checking the end array for length of 1.

Comment: @DavePritlove They are all random generated numbers in range 1,6. I just need to return the variable name that is 1. If none then call the function, so on and so forth.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood but your question seems to want the horse name *only* if it is the *only* horse to have a score of 1? I'm fairly sure your condition will always be true if the horses exist (*any* `true` either side, or both, of any chained `||`, will result in the condition being `true`, and a variable that exists is always `true`. e.g. if a variable `x` is defined with a non-falsy value,  the `(x)` in `if(x)` evaluates `true`.

Comment: note to future readers concerning my comments above. The original question included a code snippet with the conditional `if (Appaloosa || frenchTrotter || Fresian || Hackney || Faflinger || pasoFino == 1)`.

Comment: @DavePritlove Yes I want the horsename if the random number picked was 1. I see a few implementations somewhat working but not fully.

Comment: I fear you are missing the point (as are the now deleted discussions and the accepted answer): if two horses score 1, there should be no winner.

Comment: @DavePritlove Well in that case i'd just call the function to get it where only 1 value is 1 or just do a coinflip? I'm not sure

Comment: So what you are saying, contrary to all versions of your question, is that a horse scoring 1 wins, even if other horses also scored 1. That's a prefectly valid game design but is not what your question, in any of its forms is asking.

Comment: @DavePritlove Well in the case to make sure it's only 1 value I just thought it was easier to loop back until that is true instead of maybe making a 50/50 with the last 2 variants. The game flow is just 6 horses, each is just 1-6 random number (Supposed to run 1-3 times) then whichever is equal to 1 is set as var winner which matches the user input target awarding the score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code configures a result array object. Arrays are objects with nonnegative integer-like keys.

So we enumerate the competitors and push result positions calculated at random into the arrays corresponding to those positions.

Confirming the winner is as simple as reading position 1 in the array (and checking there is only one entry).

```js
const getPosition = (entrantCount = 0) => Math.floor(Math.random() * entrantCount) + 1
const resultArray = (entrantCount) => [...Array(entrantCount+1)].map(() => [])

const race = (entrants) => 
    entrants.reduce((acc, entrant) => 
        (acc[getPosition(entrants.length)].push(entrant), acc),
            resultArray(entrants.length))

const raceUntilOneWinner = (entrants) => {
    let result = null
    while(result?.[1]?.length !== 1)
        result = race(entrants)
    return result
}

const entrants = ['Appaloosa', 'French Trotter', 'Fresian', 'Hackney', 'Faflinger']
const result = raceUntilOneWinner(entrants)
console.log(`The winner is ${result[1]}.`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need to get a random name based on some of them wich condition equals 1, you can accomplish this with a simple recursion.

```js
function getWinnerHorse() {
  const horses = {
    Appaloosa: 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
    "French Trotter": 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
    Fresian: 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
    Hackney: 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
    Faflinger: 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
    "Paso Fino": 1 === Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
  };

  const horse = Object.entries(horses).find((item) => item[1]);
  if (!horse) return getWinnerHorse();
  return horse[0];
}

console.log(getWinnerHorse());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How does this exclude instances where two horse score 1 and therefore should therefore be no winner?

Comment: In the case where two or more horses scores 1, .find() will only gets the first one that find. If this validation is needed, we can implement a more complex logic with .reduce() and validate if there is more than one.

Object.entries(horses).reduce((winnerHorses, horse) => {
    const [name, value] = horse;
    if (value) winnerHorses[name] = value;
    return winnerHorses;
  }, {});

  const winners = Object.keys(results);

  if (winners.length !== 1) return getWinnerHorse();

  return winners[0]